# Excel (VBA) - Copiar dados de arquivos

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou tentando reunir dados de vários arquivos em uma unica planilha.
Em algumas pesquisas que fiz pela rede, encontrei varias sugestões, e abaixo esta o código da que encontrei e atendeu a necessidade.
Fiz alguns ajustes para adaptar ao que eu precisava porem estou com um problema no momento de colar os dados no destino.

Eu preciso "Cola Especial" para que nas células que continham resultados de formulas, seja colado o valor que estava da fórmula.

Tentei de várias formas usar um ".PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues" da vida, mas sempre da erro no código da linha abaixo:

```
'Colo na planilha principal
 ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:BA" & rTemp).Copy shPadrao.Range("B" & r)
```

**Segue código completo:**

```
Sub Importar_XLS()

Dim sPath As String, sName As String, fName As String
Dim r As Long, rTemp As Long, r2 As Long, n As Long
Dim shPadrao As Worksheet

'Para a macro executar mais rápido!
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

'A planilha onde serão colados os dados
Set shPadrao = Sheets("Dados")

'O caminho onde as planilhas estão salvas
sPath = "CaminhoDaPasta\"

'Descubro o nome do primeiro arquivo a ser aberto
sName = Dir(sPath & "*.xl*")


' Apagar o conteudo antes de copiar
shPadrao.Range("A2:BA104857").EntireRow.Delete

'Faço o loop que le todos os arquivos
Do While sName <> ""

   'Acha a ultima linha utilizada na planilha onde serao colados os dados
    r = shPadrao.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    shPadrao.Range("A" & r).Value = sName

   'O caminho + o nome do arquivo a ser aberto
    fName = sPath & sName

   'Abro o workbook a ser lido
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fName, UpdateLinks:=False

   ' Seleciona a planilha que eu quero copiar
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Calculo_Consolidado").Select
    Range("A2").Select

   'Descubro quantas linhas ele possui
    rTemp = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   'Colo na planilha principal
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:BA" & rTemp).Copy shPadrao.Range("B" & r)

   r2 = (shPadrao.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) - 1

  ' Fecho o arquivo já lido
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

  ' Tentando selecionar celula e arrastar conteudo ate a proxima vazia
   Range("A" & r).Select
   Range("A" & r).Copy
   Range("A" & r & ":" & "A" & r2 + 1).PasteSpecial
   Application.CutCopyMode = False

  'Atualizo a variavel com funcao DIR() que acha o proximo arquivo nao processado
    sName = Dir()

Loop

On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True

End With

Range("A" & r2 + 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Você quer colar o valor resultado de saída da fórmula ou a fórmula bruta em si?

Comment: Olá... Quero colar o resultado da formula

Comment: Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual é o erro? E qual o valor de `r` e de `rTemp`

Answer (score 0):

Hum... olha pelo que entendi você quer colar apenas o resultado da formula, mas você utilizou a função `Application.CutCopyMode = False` tente usar ela!

```
    'Celula que contem a formula
Range("A1").Select
'Usando a funcao Copy do VBA
Selection.Copy
'Seleciono o Destino do Paste
Range("B1").Select
'Usando a Funcao Paste Special,
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
'Informo o Metodo de copia
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Caso tenha ajudado ficarei feliz :)

Comment: Para melhor atendimento, Selecione apenas os dados o qual as celulas estejam preenchidas!

Comment: Olá Ezequiel, tudo certo? Obrigado por responder, mas essa parte do código esta funcionando. Nele existem dois momentos em que é colado informações. A parte que esta com problema no código esta aqui: 'Colo na planilha principal
     ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2:BA" & rTemp).Copy shPadrao.Range("B" & r)

Comment: Evite utilizar `.Select`

Answer (score -1):

Tenta esse:

```
wsOrigem.Range("A1").Copy
wsDestino.Range ("B1").PasteSpecial xlValues
```

Answer (score -2):

Copias dado especifico entre duas planilhas

Aba Carteira
Aba Plhan1

Aba Carteira > Produto especifico (cimento)